# regex pattern to find a line and then look for a number within the line

Tags: regex, grep

Hi I have some log files that logs operations from a software with their execution time, somewhere inside the log file I have lines that are similar to this one:

```
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM -  >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 7198ms
```

If I do `grep "BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee:" System_2013626.log`

I can get all the lines but I am trying to create a pattern that will allow me to find the lines that contain execution time over 10,000ms

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
grep -E "BuildStops\.BuildStop\.AddConsignee: ([5-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5})" System_2013626.log
```

This matches the line only if (at least) five digits are present in that position, or a four-digit number that starts with at least `5`. Also, don't forget to escape the literal dots.

Comment: is there a way to look to a specific number rather than looking for 5 digits(which means 10,000 or above) but I would like to also be able to look for stuff above 5,000ms

Comment: you Don't really need to escape the '.' or the space, it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @user2247823: Without the backslash, the dot would match *any* character. That's unlikely to be a problem in this particular situation, but you should always be explicit.

Comment: I see. Do you I need to escape the space, or should I do it jsut to be safe?

Comment: Space isn't a [metacharacter in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), so no need to escape it.

Comment: Well, from your update I guess the answer to [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323587/regex-pattern-to-find-a-line-and-then-look-for-a-number-within-the-line/17323632#comment25128832_17323632) is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
grep -E "BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: [[:digit:]]{5}" file
```

it looks for 5 digits numbers, which is the pattern numbers >=10,000 accomplish.

#### Test

```
$ cat file
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 7198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 17198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 171898ms
$ grep -E "BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: [[:digit:]]{5}" file
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 17198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 171898ms
```

---

> so I'd like it to be more dynamic, sometimes I want to look for over
>   10,000 sometime I want to look for over 4000

We can define 4000 as:
- `[4-9]` plus 3 digits.
- at least 5 digits.

```
$ cat file
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 7198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 71998ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 3198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 17198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 171898ms
12345
$ grep -E "BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: ([4-9][[:digit:]]{3}|[[:digit:]]{5})" file
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 7198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 71998ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 17198ms
6/26/2013 6:56:43 AM - >>> BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: 171898ms
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how is it looking for above 10,000. I think what you did here is that you are looking for 5 digit numbers which would mean above 10,000 but I threw this number to make it a bit simpler, and it would change depending on the situation so I'd like it to be more dynamic, sometimes I want to look for over 10,000 sometime I want to look for over 4000

Comment: Ok! It was challenging. See my updated answer, I think it should be solved now.

Comment: Careful, you need to limit the scope of your alternation.

Comment: Mmm what do you mean, @TimPietzcker? I am rather new in regex and cannot see what can be wrong in mine.

Comment: You are a genius. so if I am looking for over 6000 I would do the same but replace [4-9][[:digit:]]{3} with [6-9][[:digit:]]{3} correct?

Comment: Try it on a line that contains nothing but a five-digit number.

Comment: Yes, @user2247823, exactly.

Comment: Tim is right this "[4-9][[:digit:]]{3}" by itself would work, and it will give lines that are above 4,000 but less than 10,000 if you add teh "|[[:digit:]]{5}" it fails

Comment: Oh I see, @TimPietzcker, so I think `([4-9][[:digit:]]{3}|[[:digit:]]{5})` can make it: enclose within brackets. I tested and it works, is it a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with GNU grep

```
grep -E "BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee:.*[[:digit:]]{5,}ms"
```

Answer (score 0):

this pattern can match 10000ms, 100000ms, and so on. It does not match 9999ms.

```
grep -E 'BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee:[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]{5,}ms'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
^[1-9]([0-9]){4}
```

Start with a digit 1-9, then 4 or more digits 0

So

```
"BuildStops.BuildStop.AddConsignee: [1-9]([0-9]){4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep "BuildStops\.BuildStop\.AddConsignee: \+[1-9][0-9]\{4,\}ms"`

The `\+` after the space matches "at least one" space. The `\{4,\}` after the `[0-9]` means "at least 4" digits between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution:

```
awk '/BuildStops\.BuildStop\.AddConsignee:/ && $NF+0>10000' System_2013626.log
```

- `$NF+0` will evaluate execution time it in **integer** discarding the **ms**.